# Separating HTML tags from a javascript string into individual strings

Tags: javascript, html

I have Javascript string which is

```
 "<div>" +
 "<h2>What color does the blackcurrant berry actually have?</h2>" +
 "<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">" +
 "<audio><source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio>" +
 "</div>"
```

and the expected result is three separate strings. like

```
expected output:

console.log(title) // "<h2>What color does the blackcurrant berry actually have?</h2>"
console.log(image) // "<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">"
```

Please help with how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would render the JS string into HTML, then access it's `children`.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = "<div>" +
 "<h2>What color does the blackcurrant berry actually have?</h2>" +
 "<img src=`img_girl.jpg` alt='Girl in a jacket' width=`500` height=`600`>" +
 "<audio><source src=`horse.ogg` type='audio/ogg'></audio>" +
 "</div>"

let title = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].children[0].children[0]

let image = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].children[0].children[1]

console.log(title)
console.log(image)
```

```html
<body></body>
```